# Which boolean operator is applied when using Pandas.merge() on multiple keys

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have 2 dataframes

```
left = pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['K0', 'K0', 'K1', 'K2'],
                 'key2': ['K0', 'K1', 'K0', 'K1'],
                    'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})

right = pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['K0', 'K1', 'K1', 'K2'],
                           'key2': ['K0', 'K0', 'K0', 'K0'],
                              'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                              'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']})
```

When using `pd.merge(left,right,how='inner',on=['key1','key2'])` does the method return the values where the `left['key1'] == right['key1']` AND `left['key2'] == right['key2']` or does it use another boolean operator?

Is this characteristic related to language specific properties or is it because of the way inner, outer, left, right join works?

My intuition is that it uses an 'and' boolean operator but I need a definite answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), it's an intersection, so an AND as you described:

> how : {‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’}, default ‘inner’
>
> left: use only keys from left frame, similar to a SQL left outer join; preserve key order
>
> right: use only keys from right frame, similar to a SQL right outer join; preserve key order
>
> outer: use union of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL full outer join; sort keys lexicographically
>
> inner: use intersection of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL inner join; preserve the order of the left keys